# Order by custom Woocommerce product sorting in a WP_Query

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, product

I have created a shortcode to display products by category with the query below:

```
$atts = shortcode_atts( array (
        'type' => 'product',
        'posts' => -1,
        'category' => '',
    ), $atts, 'list_products' );

    $query = new WP_Query( array(
        'post_type' => $atts['type'],
        'posts_per_page' => $atts['posts'],
        'tax_query' => array( array(
             'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
             'field' => 'slug',
             'terms' => $atts['category'],
        ) ),
    ) );
```

This is all fine, however I am trying to use the order by attribute when I sort the products using the custom sort [shown here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/managing-products/#section-23)

I have added: `'orderby' => 'modified',` and **tried** some others from [here](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters).

Two questions:

Which attribute do I need to use to sort when using custom sorting

And

What do I need to do to make my `orderby` attribute work when added to the above query? Because it which ever attribute value I use it always sorts by published descending.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use custom sorting for Woocommerce products, it set some values for each product in `wp_posts` database table under `menu_order` column.

Then you just need to add `'orderby' => 'menu_order',` in your `WP_Query`, so in your code:

```
$atts = shortcode_atts( array (
    'type' => 'product',
    'posts' => -1,
    'category' => '',
), $atts, 'list_products' );

$query = new WP_Query( array(
    'post_type'      => $atts['type'],
    'posts_per_page' => $atts['posts'],
    'tax_query' => array( array(
         'taxonomy'  => 'product_cat',
         'field'     => 'slug',
         'terms'     => $atts['category'],
    ) ),
    'orderby'        => 'menu_order',
    // 'order'          => 'DESC',
) );
```

It will work *(by default the `order` sorting argument is set to `ASC` normally)*.

Comment: So the order by goes outside the argument list. Excellent will try and update you.

Comment: This is perfect for some reason mine was ordering DESC by default but added the ASC. Thanks